# password md5 equivalent in grub2

Tags: linux, grub, grub2

In the old version of grub, we can prevent the user modifying the boot option in menu.lst with the following line:


*menu.lst*

```
password --md5 <password>
```

In grub2, I tried to add the following lines in grub.cfg


*grub.cfg*

```
set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.xxx
```

However, every time when the system starts up it always ask me for the username and password and then it will start the Linux. Is it possible to prevent the user modifying the boot option whilst it can start up automatically without entering username/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like grub2 does not contain the feature to prevent booting via command line.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Security